# D3.js Interpolate function won't apply to edges

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

Basically what i am trying to do is call upon a function with x and y points but the function itself does nothing when called upon. 
Here's the function:

```
function interpolateLinear(points) {
  return points.join('L');
}
```

and here is the code where I draw the edges and call the function:

```
for (i=0; i<relations.length; i++) {
    g.setEdge(relations[i][0],relations[i][1], {
    lineInterpolate: interpolateLinear([[10,30], [100, 25]])
      });
}
```

When I do however call `lineInterpolate` with one of the [existing shapes](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/SVG-Shapes.md#line_interpolate), it applies perfectly, but the function call as it is does nothing.

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here?